# PCRE regex for multiple decimal coordinates using [lon,lat] format

Tags: regex, coordinates, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am trying to create a regex for [lon,lat] coordinates.

The code first checks if the input starts with '['.
If it does we check the validity of the coordinates via a regex

```
/([\[][-+]?(180(\.0{1,15})?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d{1,15})?),[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d{1,15})?|90(\.0{1,15})?)[\]][\;]?)+/gm
```

The regex tests for [lon,lat] with 15 decimals [+- 180degrees, +-90degrees]

**it should match :**

1. single coordinates :

   - [120,80];
   - [120,80]
2. multiple coordinates

   - [180,90];[180,67];
   - [180,90];[180,67]
3. with newlines

   - [123,34];[-32,21];
     [12,-67]

**it should not match:**

4. semicolon separator missing - single

   - [25,67][76,23];
5. semicolon separator missing - multiple

   - [25,67]
     [76,23][12,90];

I currently have problems with the ; between coordinates (see 4 & 5)

[jsfiddle equivalent here : http://regex101.com/r/vQ4fE0/4](http://regex101.com/r/vQ4fE0/4)

Comment: based on where Casimir was going, could it be better to use a function instead of a big regex?  If so, would it be in javascript?  The reason I ask is that comparisons, such as x<=180 are difficult in regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this (human readable) pattern:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<lon> [+-]?
        (?:
            180 (?:\.0{1,15})?
          |
            (?: 1(?:[0-7][0-9]?)? | [2-9][0-9]? | 0 )
            (?:\.[0-9]{1,15})?
        )
    )
    (?<lat> [+-]?
        (?:
            90 (?:\.0{1,15})? 
          |
            (?: [1-8][0-9]? | 9)
            (?:\.[0-9]{1,15})?
        )
    )
)

\A
\[ \g<lon> , \g<lat> ] (?: ; \n? \[ \g<lon> , \g<lat> ] )* ;?
\z
~x
EOD;
```

**explanations**:

When you have to deal with a long pattern inside which you have to repeat several time the same subpatterns, you can use several features to make it more readable.

The most well know is to use the free-spacing mode *(the x modifier)* that allows to indent has you want the pattern *(all spaces are ignored)* and eventually to add comments.

The second consists to define subpatterns in a definition section `(?(DEFINE)...)` in which you can define named subpatterns to be used later in the main pattern.

Since I don't want to repeat the large subpatterns that describes the longitude number and the latitude number, I have created in the definition section two named pattern "lon" and "lat". To use them in the main pattern, I only need to write `\g<lon>` and `\g<lat>`.

**javascript version**:

```
var lon_sp = '(?:[+-]?(?:180(?:\\.0{1,15})?|(?:1(?:[0-7][0-9]?)?|[2-9][0-9]?|0)(?:\\.[0-9]{1,15})?))';
var lat_sp = '(?:[+-]?(?:90(?:\\.0{1,15})?|(?:[1-8][0-9]?|9)(?:\\.[0-9]{1,15})?))';
var coo_sp = '\\[' + lon_sp + ',' + lat_sp + '\\]';
var regex = new RegExp('^' + coo_sp + '(?:;\\n?' + coo_sp + ')*;?$');
var coordinates = new Array('[120,80];',
                            '[120,80]',
                            '[180,90];[180,67];',
                            '[123,34];[-32,21];\n[12,-67]',
                            '[25,67][76,23];',
                            '[25,67]\n[76,23]');

for (var i = 0; i<coordinates.length; i++) {
    console.log("\ntest "+(i+1)+": " + regex.test(coordinates[i]));
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3whu3zyb/)

Comment: wow, it seems to work well but it is way above my current regex understanding (I just started). Please allow me a bit of time to grasp the meaning of your answer

Comment: @Franckl: I will add some explanations.

Comment: I use the regex is a javascript with regexInit = new RegExp('enterregexhere'); and then regexInit.test(coordInput)

Comment: @Franckl: sorry, but the features used here are not supported by the javascript regex engine. Since you used regex101.com I assumed you will use it with a PCRE regex engine. I will try to convert it to a javascript regex pattern.

Comment: very sorry for that, I got confused between the client side regex (javascript) and the other one I did just before with MongoDB (which uses PCRE)

Comment: @Franckl: do you want to check a string that is supposed to contain only coordinates or do you want to extract coordinates from a larger string that may contains several things?

Comment: the string is only supposed to contain coordinates, either single [lon,lat] or separated by a semicolon and sometime a \n if the user copy/paste a large block of coordinates

Comment: @Franckl: it's more simple like that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
^(\[([+-]?(?!(180\.|18[1-9]|19\d{1}))\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,15})?,[+-]?(?!(90\.|9[1-9]))\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,15})?(\];$|\]$|\];\[)){1,})
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/vQ4fE0/7

**Explanation**

- `^(\[`

Must start with a bracket

- `[+-]?`

May or may not contain +- in front of the number

- `(?!(180\.|18[1-9]|19\d{1}))`

Should not contain `180.`, `181-189` nor `19x`

- `\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,15})?`

Otherwise, any number containing 1 or 3 digits, with or without decimals (up to 15) are allowed

- `(?!(90\.|9[1-9]))`

The 90 check is similar put here we are not allowing `90.` nor `91-99`

- `\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,15})?`

Otherwise, any number containing 1 or 2 digits, with or without decimals (up to 15) are allowed

- `(\];$|\]$|\];\[)`

The ending of a bracket body must have a `;` separating two bracket bodies, otherwise it must be the end of the line.

- `{1,}`

The brackets can exist 1 or multiple times

---

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks materik. Your solution doesn't work for 4), I still have a match with 2 coordinates without a semicolon separator [25,67][76,23]

Comment: @Franckl Right, let me look into that.

Comment: @Franckl take a look at it now.

Comment: sorry, we are nearly there I think ! I still have an unwanted match for [25,67]\n
[76,23][12,90]; see http://regex101.com/r/vQ4fE0/8 the first coordinate [25,67] is matching

Comment: The problem with that is that you have no established end of line, so it's difficult to know where to stop matching. You see, you have those three bracket bodies on two lines, but what if there are another bracket on the next line, which should be matched. line 1-2 or line 2-3 or the whole thing line 1-3. would be easier if it always ended on ; or something. are you parsing them from a whole text field or do you get them in separate strings, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Note that you have a lot of capture groups, none of which
will give you good information because of recursive quantifiers.

```
 # /^(\[[-+]?(180(\.0{1,15})?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d{1,15})?),[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d{1,15})?|90(\.0{1,15})?)\](?:;\n?|$))+$/

 ^ 
 (                               # (1 start)
      \[
      [-+]? 
      (                               # (2 start)
           180
           ( \. 0{1,15} )?                 # (3)
        |  
           (                               # (4 start)
                ( 1 [0-7] \d )                  # (5)
             |  
                ( [1-9]? \d )                   # (6)
           )                               # (4 end)
           ( \. \d{1,15} )?                # (7)
      )                               # (2 end)
      ,
      [-+]? 
      (                               # (8 start)
           [1-8]? \d 
           ( \. \d{1,15} )?                # (9)
        |  
           90
           ( \. 0{1,15} )?                 # (10)
      )                               # (8 end)
      \]
      (?: ; \n? | $ )
 )+                              # (1 end)
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a function approach, where the function can do some of the splitting for you, as well as delegating the number comparisons away from the regex.  I tested it here:  http://repl.it/YyG/3

```
//represents regex necessary to capture one coordinate, which
//  looks like 123 or 123.13532
//  the decimal part is a non-capture group ?:
var oneCoord = '(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)';
//console.log("oneCoord is: "+oneCoord+"\n");

//one coordinate pair is represented by [x,x] 
//  check start/end with ^, $
var coordPair = '^\\['+oneCoord+','+oneCoord+'\\]$';
//console.log("coordPair is: "+coordPair+"\n");

//the full regex string consists of one or more coordinate pairs,
//  but we'll do the splitting in the function
var myRegex = new RegExp(coordPair);
//console.log("my regex is: "+myRegex+"\n");

function isPlusMinus180(x)
{
    return -180.0<=x && x<=180.0;
}

function isPlusMinus90(y)
{
    return -90.0<=y && y<=90.0;
}

function isValid(s)
{    
    //if there's a trailing semicolon, remove it
    if(s.slice(-1)==';')
    {
        s = s.slice(0,-1);
    }

    //remove all newlines and split by semicolon
    var all = s.replace(/\n/g,'').split(';');
    //console.log(all);
    for(var k=0; k<all.length; ++k)
    {        
        var match = myRegex.exec(all[k]);
        if(match===null)
            return false;

        console.log("  match[1]: "+match[1]);
        console.log("  match[2]: "+match[2]);

        //break out if one pair is bad
        if(! (isPlusMinus180(match[1]) && isPlusMinus90(match[2])) )
        {
            console.log("  one of matches out of bounds");
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}

var coords = new Array('[120,80];',
    '[120.33,80]',
    '[180,90];[180,67];',
    '[123,34];[-32,21];\n[12,-67]',
    '[25,67][76,23];',
    '[25,67]\n[76,23]',
    '[190,33.33]',
    '[180.33,33]',
    '[179.87,90]',
    '[179.87,91]');


var s;
for (var i = 0; i<coords.length; i++) {
    s = coords[i];
    console.log((i+1)+". ==== testing "+s+" ====");
    console.log("  isValid? => " + isValid(s));
}
```